# Same code: Once with InvalidOperationEcxeption, once without

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I have two projects. Both have exactly the same code. In general it is supposed to load a file, do some changes at the text and save it to a new file. This should be asnychron to change the cursor and disable the button while working.
When finished, the Form should set those things back due to a callback-function

**Class Form1**

```
Imports System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging
Imports System.Threading
Imports System

Public Class Form1
Public oldName As String
Public oldFile As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ad As New AsyncSerialize()
    Dim caller As New asyncMethodCaller(AddressOf ad.doTasks)
    Dim dummy As Integer = 0
    Dim Dialog As New OpenFileDialog
    If Dialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim CloseDialog As New SaveFileDialog
        CloseDialog.Filter = "ssd|*.ssd|scd|*.scd|icd|*.icd|iid|*iid"
        If CloseDialog.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            If System.IO.File.Exists(CloseDialog.FileName) Then
                oldName = CloseDialog.FileName
                oldFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(CloseDialog.FileName)
            End If
            Button1.Enabled = False
            Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            caller.BeginInvoke(Dialog.FileName, CloseDialog.FileName, AddressOf stopCursor, Nothing)
        Else
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Datei wurde NICHT erfolgreich gespeichert", "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub stopCursor(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim result As AsyncResult = CType(ar, AsyncResult)
    Dim caller As asyncMethodCaller = CType(result.AsyncDelegate, asyncMethodCaller)
    If caller.EndInvoke(ar) Then
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Datei wurde erfolgreich gespeichert", "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Else
        If oldFile IsNot Nothing Then
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(oldName, oldFile)
        End If
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Datei wurde NICHT erfolgreich gespeichert", "OK", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub

End Class
```

**Class AsyncSerialize**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading

Public Class AsyncSerialize

Public Function doTasks(filename As String, savename As String) As Boolean
    Dim fs As System.IO.FileStream
    Try
        fs = System.IO.File.Open(filename, IO.FileMode.Open)
        Dim serializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(ESL.SCL.SCL))
        Dim SCL As ESL.SCL.SCL
        SCL = serializer.Deserialize(fs)
        fs.Close()
        Dim Exporter As WMSExporter = New WMSExporter
        Dim SCLWMS As ESL.SCL.SCL = Exporter.Export(SCL)

        fs = System.IO.File.Create(savename)
        serializer.Serialize(fs, SCLWMS)

        fs.Close()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.IO.File.Delete(savename)
        Return False
    Finally
        If fs IsNot Nothing Then
            fs.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
End Class

Public Delegate Function asyncMethodCaller(ByVal filename As String, savename As String) As Boolean
```

When I run those projects, the one project runs without any problems and does what it should do. The other project throws an InvalidOperationException, when I try to set Button1.Enabled=True.

Any idea why the same code generates an error once and an other time not?
I suspect there must be a diiference in the configuration file. Could this be the problem?

Comment: It should always fail, you can't update UI from a worker thread.  Using a delegate's BeginInvoke() method to run code on a worker thread is a bad idea.  Use either the BackgroundWorker or the Task class to do this, they both help you to get this right.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I have to admit that I like the new code much more :)